# Inputting text from .txt into Workbook

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am trying to write a program that will take text from a .txt and input them in to cells of a Workbook. I am running into an issue though where when i'm trying to for loop through the cells and its not working.

The file is being loaded in fine and so is the excel workbook. The issue happens when trying to loop through the rows. I copied code from a tutorial I was doing previously where they did a similar thing and its not working.

```py
def LoadExcel():
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('WB/book.xlsx')
    #print(wb)
    sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
    #print(sheet)

    try:
        infile = open("text.txt", "r")
        line = infile.readline()

        for rowNum in range(1, sheet.max_row):
            print(rowNum)
            for colNum in range(1, 3):
                print(colNum)
                sheet.cell(row=rowNum, column=colNum).value = line.rstrip()

    except IOError:
        print("Error")
        sys.exit()


    wb.save('book1.xlsx')
```

The program runs fine but the excel sheet has nothing in it. The print(rowNum) under the first for loop doesnt print anything to console. So for some reason The for loop isn't working and I have no clue why.

Comment: If the worksheet doesn't have anything new in it then something in the loop try/except block isn't working. As it stands you're always inserting the same line; maybe it's blank?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it wasn't working was due to the workbook being blank (thank you to the comment). I instead changed the way it input text and it seems to work.

```py
    try:
        colNum = 1
        rowNum = 1
        infile = open("text.txt", "r")
        line = infile.readline()


        for line in infile:
            sheet.cell(row=rowNum, column=colNum).value = line.rstrip()
            line = infile.readline()
            colNum+=1

            if(colNum > 3):
                colNum = 1
                rowNum+=1
```